# How to customize the pedwait attractor choice in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I want to model the pedestrians to sit based on the social distance.

There are 10 attractors inside the node to represent the seats (1st to 10th).
Each attractor will separated by 0.5 m.

If the social distancing rule is 1m, the pedestrian will empty one seat to each other and seat only at 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th and 9th seat.

If the social distancing rule is 1.5m, the pedestrian will empty two seats to each other and seat only at 1st, 4th, 7th and 10th seat.

If the social distancing rule is 2m, the pedestrian will empty three seats to each other and seat only at 1st, 5th and 8th seat.

Currently, I have prepared an editbox to control the social distance.

How should I model the custom attractors in the pedwait and link to the control for social distance? So that the pedestrians are just sitting to the particular seats, not all the seats.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-defined way to do this, attractors are chosen internally without you having any influence.

Therefore, you would need to create an AgentType `myAttractor` which is a single attractor. Creating an agent population of it, you can then fine-control who goes where, what attractors are "off limits", etc.

However, you need to add the agent attractors dynamically to your pedestrian space, which is not straight forward. Maybe this webcast on doing something similar with the Material-Handling library helps: https://youtu.be/casVdmKC-S0